# Server Redundant PSU connections

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I'm building a few computers in [SilverStone RM22-308](https://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=922&bno=0&tb=41&area=en) rack mount cases with [SilverStone GM600-2UG](https://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=863&bno=92&tb=14&area=en) redundant power supplies. I'm installing ASUS ROG Crosshair Extreme VI E-ATX motherboards. I'm trying to find information about three connectors that are provided by PSUs:

- 2-Pin Total PFD connector
- 2-Pin PW1 connector
- 2-Pin PW2 connector

There's no explanation in any of the guides. I'm confused about their purpose and where they might connect (case backplane? or motherboard?), or if they're even needed on a non-server motherboard. Would they perhaps control the speed of the PSU fan? Have tried technical support at SilverStone, waiting to see if I get a reply. Hoping someone else can shed some light.

Comment: PFD stands for Power Failure Detection.  PW1 and PW2 are likely specific to server motherboards that support multiple power supplies. "Would they perhaps control the speed of the PSU fan?" - Absolutely not;  My guess it would be to detect if a single unit failed.

Comment: Ok great, that all makes sense. Thank you for your response @Ramhound, much appreciated.

Comment: I am also building a similar computer with the same case and power supply. Thanks for the information @Ramhound and Dom. It sucks these PSUs do not have PMBus/SMBus which is supported by a bunch of server motherboards.

Answer (score 1):

Heard back from SilverStone support.

"The 3 connectors you asked are designed for users who want to monitor and check the PSU status. There is no corresponding connector on motherboards."

Thank you @Ramhound for your response.

Comment: That's a very vague response from SilverStone. "There is no corresponding connector on motherboards."

Then where do they plug into?